# how to connect a printer with android star micronics

Tags: android, tcp

I'm having a HP printer I used [Star Microncis](http://www.starmicronics.com/) SDK and trying to connect with the HP printer.
I gave TCP:IP of the printer, but it always returns **failed to connect**.
Am I missing something?